# Не инжектится EntityManager

Tags: java-ee, junit, ejb

Создал класс, пометил аннотацией @Stateless. Добавил метод SQL запроса в БД. Код работает корректно. Но когда данный класс вызывается UnitTestом, то EntityManager не инжектится, т.е. =null.

```
@Named
@Stateless 
class RecruitmentApplications implements Serializable {

@Inject
ApplicationCredit applicationCredit;

@Inject
EntityManager em;

public RecruitmentApplications() {
}

public List<ApplicationCredit> recruitmentApplicationsWork(){
    System.out.println("Начало метода " + new Date());

    List<ApplicationCredit> list = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ApplicationCredit a", ApplicationCredit.class)
            .getResultList();
    System.out.println("list = " + list);
    return list;
}
```

А тест:

```
public class RecruitmentApplicationsTest {
private static EJBContainer ejbContainer;

private static Context ctx;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("НАЧАЛО ТЕСТА");
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File[]{new File("target/classes"), new File("target/test-classes")});
    ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
    ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    ejbContainer.close();
}

@Test
public void testCase1() throws NamingException {

    System.out.println("Начало метода \"testCase1\"");
    RecruitmentApplications recruitmentApplications =
            (RecruitmentApplications) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/RecruitmentApplications");
    assertNotNull(recruitmentApplications);
    recruitmentApplications.recruitmentApplicationsWork();
    System.out.println("Конец метода \"testCase1\"");
}
}
```

Фабрика

```
public class DatabaseProducer {
@Produces
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "VCB")
EntityManager em;
}
```

Comment: А cdi container тоже запускается? А может DatabaseProducer тоже надо как-то отметить. @@Depended или @@RequestScoped, чтобы наверняка был распознан cdi. А то ведь обычно он игнорирует классы без аннотаций

Comment: Так код работает. Не работает, если его запустить через Юнит тест. Данные аннотации не помогли.

Comment: Ну значит ваш тест не умеет в cdi

Comment: Вот и вопрос, а как сделать так, чтобы сумел?

Comment: Ну вы же где-то откопали ejbcontainer. Там же наверняка должен бить и cdi

Answer (score 0):

Поместите аннотацию `@Inject` на конструктор. И после этого в тесте вы можете просто вызывать этот конструктор и не использовать внедрение зависимостей совсем.

```
@Named
@Stateless
class RecruitmentApplications implements Serializable {

    private final ApplicationCredit applicationCredit;

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    public RecruitmentApplications(ApplicationCredit applicationCredit, EntityManager em) {
        this.applicationCredit = applicationCredit;
        this.em = em;
    }

    public List<ApplicationCredit> recruitmentApplicationsWork() {    
        List<ApplicationCredit> list = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ApplicationCredit a", ApplicationCredit.class)
                .getResultList();

        return list;
    }
}
```

Тест с использованием [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)

```
public class RecruitmentApplicationsTest {
    private EntityManager em;
    private ApplicationCredit applicationCredit;
    private RecruitmentApplications subject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        em = mock(EntityManager.class);
        applicationCredit = mock(ApplicationCredit.class);
        subject = new RecruitmentApplications(applicationCredit, em);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase1() throws NamingException {
        List<ApplicationCredit> credits = Collections.emptyList();
        when(em.createQuery(any())).thenReturn(credits);

        List<ApplicationCredit> actual = subject.recruitmentApplicationsWork();

        assertThat(actual, is(sameInstance(credits)));
    }
}
```

P.S. Не надо использовать `System.out`- используйте логирование.